# HDMI cable CEC not present

Tags: pinout, hdmi

I have a question regarding HDMI cables. I recently purchased a cable that does not have the CEC pins connected with each other. However there are certain devices that use that pin and other cables also have that pin connected.

How do I know if an HDMI cable has all the pins connected to the plug, is there some kind of specification? Why does my cable not have that CEC pin connected, is it not compliant?

Comment: I've never, ever seen an HDMI cable which deliberately left CEC unconnected. I actually had to make such a cable myself once. I suspect your cable is simply defective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot know before you buy the cable if it connects CEC or not. But it really should so either you have a damaged or non-compliant cable.

Yes, there is a specification for HDMI cables. And we cannot guess why your cable does not have CEC.

There are also cables that reportedly do not connect all ground pins, so depending if such non-compliant cables are used with non-compliant devices that also take liberties which ground pins they bother to connect, these may not work properly together.

Comment: Okay thanks, as you mentioned, my cable also does not have all ground connections, just the main ground on Pin 17. So I suppose my cable is not compliant then?

Comment: @VicTic No, if you say there are connections missing, it's not a HDMI cable, it is garbage. It might be a special cable for some special purpose, but not for consumer use. Usually, you do get what you pay for, so it does not surprise that cheap cables are scam and do not work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, helped me a lot